# Working with templates + jquery ui in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a backbone view. The view's `render` looks like this:

```
render: function()
{
    var template = _.template($("#mytemp").html() , {
        'mylabel' : "test"
    });

    this.$el.html(template);
    this.$el.css({"border" : "1px solid black"})
    this.$el.resizable({ });           
}
```

The problem is that the resizable plugin works by adding DOM elements to the `$el`. However if I use `$el.html(template)` that seems to wipe out these DOM elements, regardless of whether I put it before or after the resizable. Everything works the first time `render` is called but if `render` is called again, the resizable stops working.

Do I need to modify my template in some way?

http://jsbin.com/oyutey/2/edit

Comment: I don't understand, how can your call of .html() will wipe out something that has not yet generated which is going to happen in next statement going to be executed..

Comment: I don't understand either. But when I look at the DOM elements they simply aren't there. If I camment out the this.$el.html(template) then they are there.

Comment: what happens when you remove .html(). Means can you put here the DOM tree in both the cases.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oyutey/2/edit , I think the problem is when the view is refreshed from the model changing. If you remove the mymod.set("name","hioh"); line (at the end) it works fine but not with it added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
this.$el.html(template);
```

all of the resizable's extra DOM elements get killed off; then you bind the widget:

```
this.$el.resizable({ });
```

but resizable still thinks it is properly bound so the second `this.$el.resizable()` call does nothing. The result is that you have resizable bound to `this.$el` but its DOM elements (such as the resizing handle) no longer exist.

An easy fix is to detach the resizable before calling `this.$el.html()` and then rebind it after, something like this:

```
render: function() {
    var template = _.template($("#mytemp").html() , {
        'mylabel' : "test"
    });

    if(this.rendered) // Unbind the resizable if we've already bound it
        this.$el.resizable('destroy');
    this.$el.html(template);
    this.$el.css({"border" : "1px solid black"});
    this.$el.resizable({ }); // Set up the resizable as usual.
    this.rendered = true;    // Make a note that we've already been here.
    return this;             // This is conventional so it is a good idea to do it.
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oyutey/3/edit